# prometheus no space left on device while using remote writer

Tags: prometheus

i'am using prometheus with a remote writer  :

But i get this error after some period of running.

sg="compaction failed" err="persist head block: write compaction: write chunks: no space left on device"

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     60s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
remote_write:
  - url: "http://localhost:1234/receive"

scrape_configs:

  - job_name: 'cassandra'

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:5556']
        labels:
          instance: "server1"
```

Comment: I'm getting the same message, but none of my devices/mounts are anywhere near full (checking w/ df -h).

Answer (score 6):

Then make some space on the disk. :o)

A less snarky answer is that Prometheus keeps a database of all         data it collects and evaluates on local disk. How long data is retained in that database can be [configured from the command line](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#operational-aspects) via the `--storage.tsdb.retention` flag, which defaults to `15d`. You can reduce that as low as you're comfortable with, but seeing how you're literally running out of disk you should seriously consider allocating more disk space regardless (or delete some files, if this is a shared server).

Answer (score 4):

**The problem**: Your docker container crashed unexpectedly and on docker logs raising a red flag about ***no space left on device*** issue, mostly related

*Example of the **Error***: `target=http://pushgateway:9091/metrics msg="appending scrape report failed" err="write to WAL: log samples: write /prometheus/wal/123456: no space left on device"`

The initial suspect would be mapping the disk spaces mount points using `df -h` and look for full space capacity on volumes directory (default volumes located in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`) However, as soon as you get there you realize that this block is not full and there's extra free space already.

**Solution**: Ingested samples are grouped into blocks of two hours and kept in memory and not fully persisted yet. It is secured against crashes by a write-ahead-log (WAL) that can be replayed when the Prometheus server restarts after a crash.

**Prometheus has several flags that allow configuring the local storage** - you should use these flags in order to retain old data and turning on the wal compression for saving disk storage. more documentation about prometheus storage you can find on this [link](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/).

```
--storage.tsdb.retention.time: 
This determines when to remove old data. Defaults to 15d, 
In your use case I'd suggest to extremely increase it.
    

--storage.tsdb.wal-compression: This flag enables compression of the write-ahead log (WAL). 
Depending on your data, you can expect the WAL size to be halved with little extra cpu load.
This flag was introduced in 2.11.0 and enabled by default in 2.20.0.
Note that once enabled, downgrading Prometheus to a version below 2.11.0 will
require deleting the WAL.
```

**Example** on `docker-compose.yml`

```
prometheus:
  image: prom/prometheus:latest
  expose:
    - 9090
  ports:
    - 9090:9090
  command:
    - '--storage.tsdb.retention=60d'
    - '--storage.tsdb.wal-compression'
```